# \MFUhyphentrue is undefined control sequence

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I am using pdflatex in MikTeX 2.9 under windows 10 and the following code gives me undefined control sequence error on `\MFUhyphentrue`. My `mfirstuc` package is 2.04.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\begin{document}
\MFUhyphentrue
\capitalisewords{high-level}
\end{document}
```

The following code works but give my unwanted result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\begin{document}
%\MFUhyphentrue
\capitalisewords{high-level}
\end{document}
```

I want High-Level instead of High-level.

Comment: Welcome to me: This works for me under TL 2016 (Linux), having the same `mfirstuc` version

Comment: Of course I meant: Welcome to TeX.SX! ;-)

Comment: `\ifMFUhyphen`, `\MFUhyphentrue` and `\MFUhyphenfalse` have been added in `mfirstuc` version 2.03. If you have a previous version, it can't work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about a command introduced in a later version of the package than the one in the OP's system. The solution is installing an up-to-date version.

Comment: Hi @egreg , as I mentioned in the question, my `mfirstuc` package is 2.04. Therefore, installing an up-to-date version will not help.

Comment: @ShuoLi I can only reproduce the issue if I use an older version. Please, add the top lines of the log files, up to where the package is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps have a look at my `titlecaps` package (http://ctan.org/pkg/titlecaps) as an alternative.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\begin{document}
\titlecap{high-level high(level) high[level]}

\titlecap{Really {{high-level}} to be sure.}

\Addlcwords{a is sic}
\catcode`-=11 %
\titlecap{This [phrase] is a \textit{high-level} \LARGE statemint \normalsize[sic].}
\catcode`-=12 %

\Resetlcwords
\titlecap{This [phrase] is a \textit{high-level} \LARGE statemint \normalsize[sic].}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In version 1.2, the `\Addlcwords` command seems not working on the word after hyphen. For example `\Addlcwords{a on level}` `\titlecap{high-level}` will produce `High-Level` instead of `High-level`.

Comment: @ShuoLi Thank you for that possible bug report.  I will look into it when I get a chance.  As a workaround, one can force it lower case with `\titlecap{high-\relax level level \textnc{level}-headed top-\textnc{level}}`