# Using hyphen as a letter in command names

Tags: catcodes, renewcommand

I am using hyphen as a letter for command names.  But I allow users to rename them if necessary.  Then use `` \catcode`-=11 ``.  Suppose I keep the hyphen as a letter in command names, I wonder if users could encounter problems if they keep `` \catcode`-=11 `` for the entire document.

Comment: Briefly looking around there are a few packages that parses token list consist of `-` https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112831/typesetting-transition-metal-cluster-in-mhchem/112838#112838 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323342/mfuhyphentrue-is-undefined-control-sequence/323348#323348

Comment: did you mean to ask if there would be problems if they keep catcode 11 ??

Comment: Yes. that is what I meant.

Comment: You could have edited to fix the question (I did it now:-)

Comment: Have started editing my questions straight away after seeing comments.  Thank you so very much David.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some  LaTeX constructs that fail if `-` is catcode 11:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%\catcode`\-=11

\usepackage{array}[2021-01-01]
\usepackage{textgreek}

\begin{document}


aaa\-bbb\-ccc aaa\-bbb\-ccc aaa\-bbb\-ccc 
aaa\-bbb\-ccc aaa\-bbb\-ccc aaa\-bbb\-ccc 
aaa\-bbb\-ccc aaa\-bbb\-ccc aaa\-bbb\-ccc 
aaa\-bbb\-ccc aaa\-bbb\-ccc aaa\-bbb\-ccc 
aaa\-bbb\-ccc aaa\-bbb\-ccc aaa\-bbb\-ccc 


$ \cos-x=\cos x$

$\alpha-\beta$

\textalpha-rays

\verb-\SomeCommand-

\begin{tabular}{lll}
  1&2&3\\
  \cline{2-3}
  a&b&ct
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If you use `-` internally like `@` classically or `_` in `expl3` you could provide
`\DashLetterOn` and `\DashLetterOff`  like `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` to allow local access to that syntax in the preamble, but do not use `-` for commands intended for document use.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the catcode of the hyphen to letter in a document is a very bad idea. A few examples for a test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\catcode`-=11

\tikz\draw(0,0)--(1,0); %errors

some long\-word\-with\-hyphenation %errors

\setlength{\parindent}{-1cm} %errors
\end{document}
```

which errors with

```
! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.86 \tikz\draw(0,0)-
                     -(1,0);
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.88 some long\-word
                    \-with\-hyphenation
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.88 some long\-word\-with
                          \-hyphenation
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.88 some long\-word\-with\-hyphenation
                                       
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   -
l.90 \setlength{\parindent}{-1cm}
                                 
? 
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   -
l.90 \setlength{\parindent}{-1cm}
```